# ACF wp_query, получить конечное поле цепочки, которые в repeater->field->repeater->FIELD

Tags: php, wordpress, acf, wp-query

Нужно достучатся до поля PASSWORD

Получить страну получается, а вот написать правильный алгоритм по поиску поля PASSWORD не получается

Пытаюсь сделать вот так:

```
add_filter('posts_where', 'yanco_posts_where');
function yanco_posts_where( $where ) {
    $where = str_replace( "meta_key = 'repeater_machines_password_repeater_$", "meta_key LIKE 'repeater_machines_%_password_repeater_%", $where );
    return $where;
}

    if(isset($_GET['password'])) {
        $password = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['password'] );
        $meta_query[] = array(
            // 'key' => 'repeater_machines_$_password', // Format: repeater_field + _ + $ + _ + repeater_sub_field password_repeater
            'key' => 'repeater_machines_$_country_password_repeater_$_password',
            'value' => $password,
            'compare' => '='
        );
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzd2G.png

Comment: Покажите свой код

Comment: Добавил код в пост

Comment: Есть идеи, как можно получить поле ?

Comment: repeater->field->repeater->FIELD - как репитер может быть внутри поля?

Comment: repeater внутри repeater
Тоесть, первый repeater содержет одно текстовое поле и еще один repeater

Comment: Если я правильно понял и структура такая: repeater_machines > password_repeater > password, то нужно заменить repeater_machines_$_country_password_repeater_$_password на repeater_machines_password_repeater_$_password

Comment: Прикрепил фото структуры
repeater_machines в нем текстовое поле country и еще один repeater (password_repeater) и в нем текстовое поле которое я должен получить  -  PASSWORD